# Link filter(across()) statements with | (OR) instead of & (AND)

Tags: r, dplyr

How do I filter a dataframe `df` for all rows where one or more of `columns_to_check` meet a condition. As an example: Where is at least one cell NA?

```
df <- tibble(a = c('x', 'x', 'x'),
             b = c(NA,  'x', 'x'),
             c = c(NA,   NA, 'x'))
columns_to_check <- c('b', 'c')
```

Checking where *all* columns are `NA` is straightforward:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  filter(across(all_of(columns_to_check), ~ !is.na(.x)))

#> # A tibble: 1 x 3
#>   a     b     c    
#>   <chr> <chr> <chr>
#> 1 x     x     x
```

But (how) can I combine the `filter()` statements created with `across()` using OR?

Answer (score 2):

Here's an approach with `reduce` from `purrr`:

```
df %>%
  filter(reduce(.x = across(all_of(columns_to_check), ~ !is.na(.x)), .f = `|`))
```

This works because `across` returns a list of logical vectors that are length `nrow(df)`.

You can see that behavior when you execute it in `mutate`:

```
df %>%
+   mutate(across(all_of(columns_to_check), ~ !is.na(.x)))

# A tibble: 3 x 3
  a     b     c    
  <chr> <lgl> <lgl>
1 x     FALSE FALSE
2 x     TRUE  FALSE
3 x     TRUE  TRUE
```

Therefore, you can reduce them together with `|` to get one logical vector. You don't need `.x` or `.f`, they are only there for illustrative purposes.

Comment: Thanks! This is even clearer than the `rowSums()` approach because it makes the `|` more explicit.

Comment: The `rowSums` approach is almost certainly faster though.

Answer (score 2):

My mistake, this *is* documented in `vignette("rowwise")`:

```
df %>%
  filter(rowSums(across(all_of(columns_to_check), ~ !is.na(.x))) > 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution could be:

```
df %>%
 filter(across(all_of(columns_to_check), ~ !is.na(.x)) == TRUE)

  a     b     c    
  <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 x     x     <NA> 
2 x     x     x
```